# Switch widget textOn and textOff text is not appearing in lowercase

Tags: android

Android Switch widget textOn and textOff text is always appearing in uppercase. Is there anyway to change the case without custom xml file?

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Switch"
    android:textOff="@string/on"
    android:textOn="@string/off"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: please post your xml file

Comment: post your portion of strings.xml including @string/on and @string/off

Comment: @mTak <string name="on">on</string>
    <string name="off">off</string>

Comment: have you tried this in your code ? `switch1.setTransformationMethod(null);`

Comment: no let me try this.

Comment: yes as @Umair suggested, try  switch1.setTransformationMethod(null);

Comment: @BiswanathMaity please try and tell me if it worked for you . On the other hand if you want to completely get rid of this problem make sure to add `textAllCaps='false'` in your application style.

Comment: @umair its not working. I did also textAllCaps= 'false'

Comment: @BiswanathMaity ok can you tell me is it api v-21 or greater and what does your activity extending like AppCompat etc. ?

Comment: activity extends AppCompatActivity and my application base theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: @BiswanathMaity I have used your code and it's working fine,. Have you tried using `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` instead of simple switch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Switch` to `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` in xml and 
Create this style in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="SwitchTheme">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

and add this to your Switch xml:

```
android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme"
```

Comment: I have tried this but its not working in my project.. Have u tried this ?

Comment: I'm glad_________

Answer (score 0):

set a custom style and use it for the switch in your xml:

```
<style name="MySwitch" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
<item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
```

You could also try to use this programatically:

```
switch1.setTransformationMethod(null);
```